# Apollo seems to refresh, when state is mapped to props, how can i prevent it?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, apollo

I've build a component which basically list entries in a table, on top of that, i have another component to which filters can be applied. It all works really great with Apollo.

I'm trying to add deep linking into the filters, which on paper seems incredible simple, and i almost had i working.

Let me share some code.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ activeObject }) => ({ activeObject });

@withRouter
@connect(mapStateToProps, null)
@graphql(FILTER_REPORT_TASKS_QUERY, {
  name: 'filteredTasks',
  options: (ownProps) => {
    const filters = queryString.parse(location.search, { arrayFormat: 'string' });

    return {
      variables: {
        ...filters,
        id: ownProps.match.params.reportId,
      },
    };
  },
})
export default class TasksPage extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    filteredTasks: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    activeObject: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const filters = queryString.parse(location.search, { arrayFormat: 'string' });
    this.state = { didSearch: false, initialFilters: filters };
    this.applyFilter = this.applyFilter.bind(this);

  }

  applyFilter(values) {
    const variables = { id: this.props.match.params.reportId };
    variables.searchQuery = values.searchQuery === '' ? null : values.searchQuery;
    variables.categoryId = values.categoryId === '0' ? null : values.categoryId;
    variables.cardId = values.cardId === '0' ? null : values.cardId;

    /*
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: `${ this.props.history.location.pathname }`,
      search: '',
    }); 
    return null;
    */

    this.props.filteredTasks.refetch(variables);
    this.setState({ didSearch: true });
  }

  ..... Render functions.
```

Basically it calls the apply filter method, when a filter is chosen.

Which all works great, my problem is that when the `activeObject` is updated (By selecting a entry in the list). It seems to run my HOC graphql, which will apply the filters from the URL again, ignoring the filters chosen by the user.

I tried to remove the query strings from the url, once filters are applied, but i get some unexpected behavior, basically it's like it doesn't fetch again.

How can i prevent Apollo from fetching, just because the redux pushes new state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by changing the order of the HOC's.

```
@graphql(FILTER_REPORT_TASKS_QUERY, {
  name: 'filteredTasks',
  options: (ownProps) => {
    const filters = queryString.parse(location.search, { arrayFormat: 'string' });
    return {
      variables: {
        ...filters,
        id: ownProps.match.params.reportId,
      },
    };
  },
})
@withRouter
@connect(mapStateToProps, null)
```